# multiprocessing, pool and two lists

Tags: python

```
>>> from multiprocessing import Pool

>>> def f(x, y):
...     return x*y

>>> p = Pool(3)

>>> p.map(f, [1,2,3], [4,5,6])
```

And I look errors `TypeError: unorderable types: list() <= int()`.
How to use `Pool` with 2 lists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with the `map` function not the `Pool` object. For this case, `starmap` would be a good choice like this:

```
p.starmap(f, zip([1,2,3], [4,5,6]))
```

From python 3.3 [`starmap`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap) was added to the `Pool` object

Comment: The mistake was on my side. Nice one! +1

Comment: Actually, your comment made me research a bit further and see that I was unnecessarily importing `starmap` and notice it was added in 3.3, we'll have to see what version OP is using

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand how you want to order your parameters but the idea is to have a list of tuples because your function takes 2 arguments, so something like this :

```
p.map(f, [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)])
```

and make f take a tuple as argument

```
def f(t):
    return t[0] * t[1]
```