# ONNX Runtime Inference | session.run() multiprocessing

Tags: parallel-processing, multiprocessing, inference, onnx, onnxruntime

**Goal: run Inference in parallel on multiple CPU cores**

I'm experimenting with Inference using [simple_onnxruntime_inference.ipynb](https://github.com/onnx/onnx-docker/blob/master/onnx-ecosystem/inference_demos/simple_onnxruntime_inference.ipynb).

Individually:

```py
outputs = session.run([output_name], {input_name: x})
```

Many:

```py
outputs = session.run(["output1", "output2"], {"input1": indata1, "input2": indata2})
```

Sequentially:

```py
%%time
outputs = [session.run([output_name], {input_name: inputs[i]})[0] for i in range(test_data_num)]
```

---

This Multiprocessing [tutorial](https://www.machinelearningplus.com/python/parallel-processing-python/) offers many approaches for parallelising any tasks.

However, I want to know which approach would be best for `session.run()`, with or without `outputs` being passed.

**How do I Inference all outputs and inputs together, in parallel?**

**Code:**

```py
import onnxruntime
import multiprocessing as mp

session = onnxruntime.InferenceSession('bert.opt.quant.onnx')

i = 0
# First Input
input_name = session.get_inputs()[i].name
print("Input Name  :", input_name)

# First Output
output_name = session.get_outputs()[i].name
print("Output Name  :", output_name)  

pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())

# PARALLELISE THIS LINE
outputs = [session.run([], {input_name: inputs[i]})[0] for i in range(test_data_num)]
# outputs = pool.starmap(func, zip(iter_1, iter_2))

pool.close()

print(results)
```

---

**Update**: this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49026821/17840900) suggests using `starmap()` and `zip()` in order to pass a function name and 2 separate iterables.

Replacing line with this:

```py
outputs = pool.starmap(session.run, zip([output_name], [ {input_name: inputs[i]}[0] for i in range(test_data_num) ]))
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-0aab302a55eb> in <module>
     25 #%%time
     26 #outputs = [session.run([output_name], {input_name: inputs[i]})[0] for i in range(test_data_num)]
---> 27 outputs = pool.starmap(session.run, zip([output_name], [ {input_name: inputs[i]}[0] for i in range(test_data_num) ]))
     28 
     29 pool.close()

<ipython-input-45-0aab302a55eb> in <listcomp>(.0)
     25 #%%time
     26 #outputs = [session.run([output_name], {input_name: inputs[i]})[0] for i in range(test_data_num)]
---> 27 outputs = pool.starmap(session.run, zip([output_name], [ {input_name: inputs[i]}[0] for i in range(test_data_num) ]))
     28 
     29 pool.close()

KeyError: 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
def run_inference(i):
    output_name = session.get_outputs()[0].name
    return session.run([output_name], {input_name: inputs[i]})[0]  # [0] bc array in list

outputs = pool.map(run_inference, [i for i in range(test_data_num)])
```

Anyone feel free to critique

Comment: How has performance been for you so far doing this this way?

Comment: Haven't a baldy; I've since moved on to other work